# Differentiate between Facebook user and event ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I detect programmatically wether a Facebook ID `user` over `event` ID is? Are there any intervals where ID come from? I.e. `10211282278486891` is my user ID, and `1774156412659580` is an event ID. Looking for a fast way, without any web service call.

Comment: No there are not special intervals

Answer (score 0):

Search for fields specific for the user - for example, there is no "first_name" field in an event and you do not need extra permission to get that field.

```
/id?fields=first_name
```

Another solution that is probably better:

```
/id?metadata=1
```

With that API call, you get a "type" field that tells you if it´s a user profile or event.

Comment: Is it any faster way? Without calling a web service? Just knowing the ID?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: please check out the changes in my answer, i just found out about a metadata parameter that should work for you.